# Why discounted reward function is reversed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning

I'm solving an MIT lab on Reinforcement Learning and am stuck on the reward function.
The particular code block is this:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/aamini/introtodeeplearning/blob/master/lab3/solutions/RL_Solution.ipynb#scrollTo=5_Q2OFYtQ32X&line=19&uniqifier=1

A simpler version of the relevant code is:

```
import numpy as np

rewards=[0.,0,0,0,0,1]
discounted_rewards = np.zeros_like(rewards)
R = 0
for t in reversed(range(0, len(rewards))):
    # update the total discounted reward
    R = R * .95 + rewards[t]
    discounted_rewards[t] = R
discounted_rewards
```

Which gives output as:

```
array([0.77378094, 0.81450625, 0.857375, 0.9025, 0.95 ,1.])
```

The provided explanation is that we want to encourage having rewards sooner rather than later. How does using `reversed` in the for loop help with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reversed is necessary so that each reward is multiplied x times by the discount factor where x is the number of timesteps that the reward is away from the present. Besides, since it´s a cumulative reward it adds the next reward to the prior reward. This wouldn´t be able without reverse.

With the reverse, the last reward is the first reward that will be added to R and then in each iteration as the loop continues it will be multiplied by 0.95 for the number of timesteps that occurred before the reward event.

What the loop does is this:

```
R = 0
R += 0.95 ** 5 * 1
R += 0.95 ** 4 * 0
R += 0.95 ** 3 * 0
R += 0.95 ** 2 * 0
R += 0.95 ** 1 * 0
R += 0
```

Edit:

The output you get is the cumulative discounted reward. The first index in your output list means that your agent has at that timestep a cumulated discounted reward of 0.7737 for the following action-state tuples. Then further you go into the future (increase the list index) your discounted reward will be higher since you´re approaching the net reward of 1 (winning the game).

Comment: So I understand how the loop gives the output, I guess i'm not able to understand the reasoning for doing it with reversed and the interpretation of the output.

Comment: I explained the reasoning in my post. The reverse is responsible for the multiplying of a reward with the number of timesteps that it differs from today.

Comment: If you can also add the interpretation, I think that will help.

Comment: @ZainKhaishagi I added an edit to my original post.